# Activity Dialog over Incoming call screen

Tags: android

I am trying to show the Caller details whenever there is an Incoming call over the Incoming call screen.

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which starts an `Intent Service` , which further starts an Activity over the Incoming call screen. Everything is working fine except the slider where user answers the call disappears. Once i click back , it comes again and everything is okay from that point onwards.

What i want is to show the `Activity Dialog` over the Incoming call screen.
Dialog should act to the User touch events, so that user can slide the activity dialog anywhere over the incoming call screen. 
User should be able to answer the call as well when Activity Dialog is on the incoming call screen.

By Activity Dialog i mean Activity which is shown as a Dilaog i.e. with theme Dialog.

Warm Regards

```
public class IncomingCallDetailsDialogActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    Log.e("TAG", "Message = "+message);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_activity);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

        }
```

Comment: Moving a Dialog on the incoming call screen is done.

Comment: answer your own question for others help ?

Comment: I have done with only "Moving a Dialog thing over incoming screen ". I am unable to pick the call when Dialog is over the incoming call screen.<Which is the main issue i am facing >